# How to solve problem like this - even & odd function

Tags: calculus, functions

This is my problem, Consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{e^{x}}$ , Where $x\epsilon [0,\infty[$

1) Define the function $g:\Re \rightarrow \Re$ such that $g$ is an even function and $g=f$  on $[0,\infty[$

---

Some one please help me to figure out this problem.

(*is function $g$ can be a piecewise function?, Or piecewise function can be even or odd? )

Comment: The only requirement for even-ness is that $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$, which does not exclude piecewise ones

Comment: So an even function is one where $f(x) = f(-x)$, you can incorporate the modulus function here to achieve such a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

For a function to be even, you must have $$g(-x) = g(x)$$ meaning that it's symmetric around the $y$ axis. So, just piecewise define your function $g(x)$ to be equal to $f(x)$ on the right to the $y$-axis, and to be equal to $f(-x)$ on the left side.

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}f(x)& \text{if } x \geq 0\\ f(-x) & \text{if } x < 0\end{cases} $$
Meaning
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{e^x}& \text{if } x \geq 0\\ \frac{1}{e^{-x}} & \text{if } x < 0\end{cases} $$

You get an even function which is symmetrical around the $y$ axis now. ( 
You can also use the absolute value function to simplify the expresion, that is:
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{e^{|x|}} = e ^{-|x|}$$

Side note: The function is not differentiable at $x=0$ anymore, but the function value there is $g(0)=1$. (Limit from both sides approaching $0$ exist and agree)

Comment: Thank you very much, It's really help me. I had 2 of these question. Now I can solve them :)